# Variable value is determined by function call

Tags: python

This is probably weird but I would like to declare a variable without a fixed value, but "linked" in some way to the result of a function. The goal is for the end user to manipulate a variable, but each time the variable's value is used, its value may change.

This is the current result I get:

```
from random import randint

def randomfun():
    return randint(1, 100)

an_int = randomfun
print an_int    # Print the function object
print an_int()  # Print the result of randomfun()
```

What I would like to get is `print an_int` to actually call `randomfun()`, but without having to add the parenthesis, and the type of `an_int` should be `randomfun`'s return type.

Comment: I do not understand the question. To declare a variable without a value, you declare it as None. "linked" in some way is meaningless, difficult to understand what you mean by that. You may manipulate the variable from within the scope without any issue. If you want to change a variable sometimes, and not otherwise, you need abstraction (an accessor method). Are you trying to make it have 50% chance of calling randfun, and 50% chance of changing the value?

Comment: Sorry, I do misunderstand.

Comment: You probably know this, but encountering a variable like that in a program could lead to some REALLY frustrating debug sessions.

Comment: Yes, don't worry about it, I will make it **very** clear and use this only in very particular circumtances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`an_int` is an object. It won't change its value unless you change it. However, you could change the way the object is represented:

```
from random import randint

class RandomFun(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return str(randomfun())

def randomfun():
    return randint(1, 100)

an_int = RandomFun()
print an_int    
print an_int
```

yields (something like)

```
57
19
```

Comment: +1: Very clever. Is there any way to actually use `an_int` as an integer?

Comment: Clever solution and fits what GuillaumeA explicitly asked for, but might not fit what he actually needs.

Comment: @Blender: I don't you could use a subclass of `int` since `int`s are immutable.

Comment: Exactly what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks @unutbu!