# Randomizing integer behavior

Tags: python, int, subclass, metaclass

After seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252726/variable-value-is-determined-by-function-call), I started wondering: is it possible to write a class that *behaves* like a random integer?

I managed to find some overridable methods with `dir()`:

```
class RandomInt(int):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return randint(1, 100) + other

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return randint(1, 100) * other

    def __div__(self, other):
        return randint(1, 100) / other

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return randint(1, 100) - other

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(randint(1, 100))
```

But I feel like there's a more elegant way to inject `randint(1, 100)` into each method that accepts a `self` argument.

Is there a way to do this without re-writing the entire `int` class from scratch?

Something like:

```
>>> x = RandomInt()
>>> x + 1
2
>>> x + 1
74
>>> x * 4
152
```

Comment: Are you talking about dynamically defining each function(in list of functions add, mul, subtract etc) to return randint passed to each method? Edit: no point of even asking that it says it in the question

Comment: @jamylak: Something like that. As long as the end result is that `RandomInt`'s "value" appears random for each method.

Comment: @Blender: ah, for *every* method. Yes, then you need to create methods.. And that'll work only if the `int` is the left-hand operand *or* if the left-hand operand doesn't itself define a hook for the operation.

Comment: @Blender `__repr__` needs just `self`, not need of the `other`

Comment: The shortest answer would be: `Yes` but then I received a prompt saying: `Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 3.` :)..

Comment: Update on my answer!

Comment: You probably want `repr` to return something like `RandomInt(1, 100)` as opposed to a random integer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a different answer because it is very different from the other one that I posted.
(and I felt this deserved to be separate)

The Code:

```
class RandomInt:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        attr = getattr(int, name, '')
        if attr != '':
            def wrapper(*args, **kw):
                return attr(random.randint(1, 100), *args, **kw)
            return wrapper
        else:
            raise AttributeError(
                    "'{0}' object has no attribute '{1}'".format('RandomInt',name))
```

An example run:

```
>>> x = RandomInt()
>>> x
88
>>> 1 + x # __radd__
67
>>> x*100 # __mul__
1900
>>> x+5 # __add__
50
>>> x-1000 # __sub__
-945
>>> x//5 # __floordiv__
8
>>> float(x) # __float__
63.0
>>> str(x) # __str__
'75'
>>> complex(x) # __complex__
(24+0j)
>>> sum([x]*10)
573
```

There is scope for improvement:

```
>>> x + x

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1456>", line 1, in <module>
    x + x
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'instance' and 'instance'
```

Same for `x*x`, `x/x`, and similar

---

Another version this time, similar to [@gatto's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16253384/1931274) answer:

```
import random, inspect

class RandomInt:
    def __init__(self):
        def inject(attr):
            def wrapper(*args, **kw):
                args = list(args)
                for i,x in enumerate(args):
                    if isinstance(x, RandomInt):
                        args[i] = x+0
                return attr(random.randint(1,100), *args, **kw)
            return wrapper

        for name in dir(int):
            attr = getattr(int, name)
            if inspect.ismethoddescriptor(attr):
                setattr(self, name, inject(attr))
```

And this one has support for:

```
>>> x + x
49
>>> x // x
2
>>> x * x
4958
>>> x - x
77
>>> x ** x
467056167777397914441056671494001L
>>> float(x) / float(x)
0.28
```

---

Yet another version, that uses class attributes to overcome the new-style/old-style problem (thanks @gatto):

```
import random, inspect

class RandomInt(object):
    pass

def inject(attr):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        args = list(args)
        for i,x in enumerate(args):
            if isinstance(x, RandomInt):
                args[i] = random.randint(1,100)
        return attr(*args, **kw)
    return wrapper

for name in dir(int):
    attr = getattr(int, name)
    if inspect.ismethoddescriptor(attr):
        setattr(RandomInt, name, inject(attr))
```

Output:

```
>>> x
86
>>> x
22
>>> x * x
5280
>>> [1] * x
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> x * '0123'
'0123012301230123'
>>> s[x] # s = '0123456789' * 10
'5'
```

Comment: I like how you wrapped x's in `float`, because `x / 1.0` fails =)

Comment: +1 Nice method (even though it takes longer to type than just writing the whole class again), I'm wondering why this only works for old-style classes though

Comment: @Schoolboy what I mean is try adding `object` as a base class, that would make it a newstyle class but when I tried that it didn't work

Comment: @jamylak I'll try that when I reach home from the party I'm in

Comment: Apparently Python only uses class attributes, when a newstyle class object passed to BIFs like `str`, `int` and others. You can see in [this patch](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e48ef8e3cc7f67f4bf91) that call to `__int__` looks like `o->ob_type->tp_as_number->nb_int(object)`, meaning that `__int__` belongs to a type, not to an instance. Old-style classes on the other hand have default `nb_int` implementation, that [checks](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Objects/classobject.c#L1842) for attribute presence.

Comment: @jamylak Based on what gatto mentioned, I have a new solution.. Still faces the `x/1.0` problem though.. Any ideas why?

Comment: @gatto Same as above.

Answer (score 1):

```
import inspect
from random import randint

class SelfInjecter(type):
    def __new__(self, *args, **kw):
        cls = type(*args, **kw)
        factory = cls.__factory__

        def inject(attr):
            def wrapper(self, *args, **kw):
                return attr(factory(self), *args, **kw)
            return wrapper

        for name in dir(cls):
            attr = getattr(cls, name)

            if inspect.ismethoddescriptor(attr):
                setattr(cls, name, inject(attr))

        return cls

class RandomInt(int):
    __metaclass__ = SelfInjecter
    __factory__ = lambda self: randint(1, 100)

x = RandomInt()
print x + 3, x - 3, x * 3, repr(x)
```

The code above has a few problems.

As was suggested by [Schoolboy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1931274/schoolboy), the following doesn't work properly:

```
>>> print x * x
0
```

We need to convert all arguments to our new type `RandomInt` if possible:

```
def factory(x):
    if isinstance(x, cls):
        return cls.__factory__(x)
    return x

def inject(attr):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        args = [factory(x) for x in args]
        kw = {k: factory(v) for k, v in kw}
        return attr(*args, **kw)

    return wrapper
```

Also sequence multiplication and indexing doesn't work as expected:

```
>>> [1] * x, x * '123', '123'[x]
([], '', '1')
```

This is because Python doesn't use `__index__` for `int`-inherited types:

```
class Int(int):
    def __index__(self):
        return 2

>>> x = Int(1)
>>> '012'[x], '012'[x.__index__()]
('1', '2')
```

Here is the code from Python 2.7.4 implementation:

```
/* Return a Python Int or Long from the object item
   Raise TypeError if the result is not an int-or-long
   or if the object cannot be interpreted as an index.
*/
PyObject *
PyNumber_Index(PyObject *item)
{
    PyObject *result = NULL;
    if (item == NULL)
        return null_error();
    if (PyInt_Check(item) || PyLong_Check(item)) {
        Py_INCREF(item);
        return item;
    }
    if (PyIndex_Check(item)) {
        result = item->ob_type->tp_as_number->nb_index(item);
        if (result &&
            !PyInt_Check(result) && !PyLong_Check(result)) {
            PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                         "__index__ returned non-(int,long) " \
                         "(type %.200s)",
                         result->ob_type->tp_name);
            Py_DECREF(result);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, it checks for `int` and `long` first and only then tries to call `__index__`.

Solution is to inherit from `object` and clone/wrap attributes from `int`, or actually I like [Schoolboys's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16253796/521590) more, I guess it can be corrected in a similar manner as well.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to have an `__call__` method, that returns an random number.

```
class RandomInt(int):
    def __call__(self):
        return random.randint(1, 100)
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self() + other

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self() * other

    def __div__(self, other):
        return self() / other

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self() - other

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self())
```

Example Run

```
>>> x = RandomInt()
>>> x * 3
81
>>> x + 3
56
>>> x - 4
68
>>> x / 4
2
```

Comment: Right, but then you'd have to write `x() + 1` instead of `x + 1`.

Comment: It's not "hacky" but doesn't answer the question since this doesn't act like an int

Comment: @Blender No, it would still be `x + 1` on the user's side.

Comment: @jamylak Why?? <need-chars>

Comment: @Schoolboy: So what purpose does the `__call__` method serve?

Comment: @Blender It is just used in place of `randint`, but looks better, and has more readabilitiy :)

Comment: @Schoolboy you still had to write out all of those functions exactly as Blender did in the question...

Comment: @jamylak Yes, that's the problem. It's solved in the other one though.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the methods at runtime:

```
def add_methods(*names):
    def the_decorator(cls):
        for name in names:
            def the_function(self, other):
                 return cls(random.randint(0, 100))
            setattr(cls, name, the_function)
        return cls
    return the_decorator


@add_methods('__add__', '__mul__', '__sub__')
class RandomInt(int):
    pass
```

This allow you to select which method should act randomly.

Note that you may be tempted to use things like [`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) or [`__getattribute__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) to customize how the attributes are accessed and avoid setting the methods explicitly in the class, but this will not work with special methods, since their look up [does not pass through the attribute-access methods](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-special-lookup).

Comment: You can't just `                 return random.randint(0, 100)` you need to actually call the base function with `other` as a parameter. Eg. If I want to do `1000+ a` this wont work

Comment: @jamylak AFAIK the only problem that my first implementation had was returning a plain `int` instead of a `RandomInt`. I don't see where the problem is regarding `1000 + a`. That's a call to `__radd__` and not `__add__`, hence you simply have to add `'__radd__'` in the list of methods to be added to the class.